# how to print dictionary row data by two values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, row, key-value

I'm pretty new in python and i have a question regarding dictionary.
i would like to check if two values "day" and "month" are exist in one of the dictionary data rows.
if they are, i would like to print the desired row data in the dictionary.
i only succeeded one value "day" or "month" but not both. any idea how to do it?

```
#birthday.csv file:
name,email,year,month,day
Test1,test1@gmail.com,1961,03,25
Test2,test2@gmail.com,1977,03,21

#python code:
import pandas
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
day = int(now.strftime("%d"))
month = int(now.strftime("%m"))

with open("birthdays.csv") as read_file:
    read = pandas.read_csv(read_file)
    dictionary = read.to_dict('list')
    print(dictionary)
output:
{'name': ['Test1', 'Test2'], 'email': ['test1@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com'], 'year': [1961, 1977], 'month': [3, 3], 'day': [25, 21]}
```

i tried:

```
if str(month) in str(dictionary['month']) and str(day) in str(dictionary['day']):
```

i do not know how to print the data row in this way that if for example "day and "month" are in the row:Test2,test2@gmail.com,1977,03,21 it will print this row.

Comment: you don't need to convert to string. Just do `if month in dictionary['month'] and day in dictionary['day']:`

Comment: Rather than converting to a dictionary, is there a reason you're not simply printing the row of the dataframe that contains the data i.e. `print(read[(read.month == month) & (read.day == day)])`

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I was looking for, simply as that.